# Using android support library 23.2 in build.gradle crashes app (XmlPullParserException: XmlPullParserException: invalid drawable tag vector)

Tags: android, svg, custom-controls, android-support-library

The app is working just fine when using support library v23.1.1 plugin and run under Android 4.4.4 (API 19):

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
```

however when I build it using [newer version (23.2)](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) of android support library it crashes:

`XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector`

This happens when the app wants to inflate an alert dialog with a simple custom view. The custom view uses an XML file containing a `<shape>` tag as one of its drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid
    android:color="@android:color/white" >
</solid>

<corners
    android:radius="5dp">
</corners>

<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/AppColor" />

</shape>
```

Though I can't specifically pinpoint this SVG based drawable in the crash logs, but my guess is since Google introduced support for `VectorDrawables`, it somehow clashes with my app.

Any hint or input on how to pinpoint the culprit is appreciated.

Comment: as I suspected the older support library creates .png files for `<shape>` drawables which works fine, but the new one creates `svg` files that have `vector` tag that somehow API 19 can not handle it. I even tried following their suggestion to turn the png creation on and off `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` but that didn't help.

Comment: You’ll note this new attribute only exists in the version 2.0 of the Gradle Plugin. If you are using Gradle 1.5 you’ll instead use


 // Gradle Plugin 1.5  
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     generatedDensities = []  
  }  

  // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
 }

http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

Comment: In which directory did you put your SVGs in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out there were two separate issues:

- I was using a plain `RadioButton` in my XML files. Changing it to `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton` fixed the problem.
- Second, as the blog post was suggesting I had to wrap some of the drawables into **container** drawables so the support library could use them when doing vector based drawing. For example, in one of my custom buttons, I had vector based background saved in `dialog_bg.xml`, `button_round_bg.xml` and `button_round_bg_2.xml`.

  To fix that I had to put them in one of the containers (such as [State list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList), [Inset](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Inset) or [LevelList](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LevelList)). This wrapper was saved to a filed called `vector_wrapper.xlm`:

```xml
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/dialog_bg"
        android:maxLevel="1"
        android:minLevel="1" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_round_bg"
        android:maxLevel="2"
        android:minLevel="2" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_round_bg_2"
        android:maxLevel="3"
        android:minLevel="3" />
</level-list>
```

Now I would change my custom button's background to say

```xml
<customButton
    android:background="@drawable/vector_wrapper"
</customButton>
```

Since the wrapper now has three drawables, I can select them in the Java code according to my needs:

```java
customButton btnSave = (customButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
btnSave.getBackground().setLevel(3);
```

You do not need to the container wrapper if your view is `Image`-based view as the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35634518/1052405) by @themichaelscott is suggesting, in that case just change the src to `app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"`

Answer (score 13):

I ran into a similar issue.  I was getting the same error because I was still using the android:src attribute instead of app:srcCompat when setting the source of my ImageView

Changing this attribute everywhere you're referencing a vector drawable will fix your issue.

Old:

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
  android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />
```

New:

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
  app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />
```

Comment: the app:srcCompat can only be used for Image-based views, I am using Button-based views and according to the blog post it doesn't support app:srcCompat

Comment: giving "Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix" error

Comment: The answer from @theMichaelScott answer also proved to work with a FloatingActionButton as well        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton 
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_gps_fixed_24dp" />

Comment: Saved my time! :)